# Block Unwanted Domain Name Pointing to My Site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The domain name 2nicksplumbing.com that is privately registered is being indexed by Google and directed to NicksPlumbing.com

I have attempted the following to block it with no luck...

- Blocked the domains ip in cPanel
- Deny method in .htaccess file
- RewriteCond method in .htaccess file (code below)

Can anyone suggest why I cannot block this domain name from pointing to our site?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.nicksplumbing.com/404.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 2nicksplumbing\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nicksplumbing\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nicksplumbingrepair\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nicksplumbingrepair\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.nicksplumbing.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ https://www.nicksplumbing.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: IF YOU'RE GOING TO DOWN VOTE A POST AT LEAST SAY WHY!!!
Explain how "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"? I tried 3 different ways that I researched!

Comment: Rhino, calm down. A downvote is not the end of the world (it wasn't me btw). Are you wanting to block this website or are you trying to stop Google from crawling and indexing it? Because if you want to stop Google, then you would do that using the `robots.txt` file.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion but I had done research on blocking a domain using the robots.txt file but learned it doesn't work.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/XspeRNQBXMo

Do you know of another way that does work with the robots.txt file?

Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to block the domain, then yes, you'd use `.htaccess`. I only suggested `robots.txt` as you could use it to stop Google from indexing and crawling that specific domain / URLs.

Comment: At the least I would like to have Google not index it so would love to get the robots.txt file working like you suggest but as you can see from the link I provided it doesn't work that way. Do you know of another way that does work with the robots.txt file? I appreciate your time!

Comment: You have access to `2nicksplumbing.com` at all? If so, inside the `robots.txt` file you would add: `User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /` this would then stop google from crawling it.

Comment: I do not have access to 2nicksplumbing.com and it is privately registered. Have no clue why someone has taken the time to purchase the name and point it to our site but it is unprofessional looking and it's actually getting some traffic somehow.

Comment: When I check what is going on in my browser in the network panel, it doesn’t send any referrer to begin with. It notes `Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`, but I don’t think that plays a role here, because if anything, we’re upgrading. But the other site could theoretically specify `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer` explicitly, which would kill any attempt at evaluating this for good. You can not redirect based on info that isn’t there in the first place.

Comment: FYI, you should not specify `ErrorDocument 404` as an absolute URL - that will cause a _redirect_ to that URL, so search engines etc. will lose the 404 response code for the originally requested resource.

Answer (score 2):

I see you've tried to block the domain using `HTTP_REFERER`, the other method to try is using the `env=bad` directive:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "2nicksplumbing\.com" bad_referer
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "www\.2nicksplumbing\.com" bad_referer

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=bad_referer
```

The above will allow access to your website from everything that ***isn't*** on your `bad_referer` list. For more information you can read the [Apache Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) for this.

Clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

I will add however, it doesn't seem like this private domain is doing harm to your website? It is simply referring traffic to your website.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work once again. I appreciate the effort. Can't understand why neither of these htaccess methods are working. ugh

Comment: It is strange. I'm thinking perhaps something in your `.htaccess` is affecting it, that or your hosting is preventing it. Try putting these news `.htaccess` rules to the top so that they're run first.

Comment: Just a point, I noticed you have a couple of `[L]` flags in your `.htaccess`. This stands for `LAST` and stops any other rules running past them. So make sure as I said previously, to put these rules right to the top while testing.